# Select into a variable with a "case" expression

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to assign a variable with the result of a case within a select statement.
I've tried different approaches:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    declare truefalse varchar(100);

    SELECT truefalse = CASE cfgvalue when 'TRUE' THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END
    from cfg where cfglabel = 'DO_NOT_DISPLAY_WORK_ITEMS_IN_RECEIPT_CONFIRMATION_WIN';
END;
$$
```

and then

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    declare truefalse varchar(100);

    SELECT CASE cfgvalue when 'TRUE' THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END 
    into truefalse
    from cfg where cfglabel = 'DO_NOT_DISPLAY_WORK_ITEMS_IN_RECEIPT_CONFIRMATION_WIN';
END;
$$
```

and also with the other "case" syntax: case when x=y then z else r end.
No luck so far - I get error message:
type "truefalse" does not exist.
Can anyone shed light on my error?

Comment: nameless horse, thanks, you're a life saver! I'm new to postgres and failed to find the relevant documentation.

Comment: Note that it's a CASE _expression_. A (PL/pgSQL) CASE statement is something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html), the `declare` section goes before the begin. If you do that, your the second PL/pgSQL block will work.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  truefalse varchar(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE cfgvalue when 'TRUE' THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END 
      into truefalse
    from cfg where cfglabel = 'DO_NOT_DISPLAY_WORK_ITEMS_IN_RECEIPT_CONFIRMATION_WIN';
END;
$$
```

But why not use a proper boolean value?

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  truefalse boolean;
BEGIN
    SELECT cfgvalue = 'TRUE'
      into truefalse
    from cfg where cfglabel = 'DO_NOT_DISPLAY_WORK_ITEMS_IN_RECEIPT_CONFIRMATION_WIN';
END;
$$
```

If the `cfgvalue` always stores the strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` you can even cast it directly:

```
    SELECT cfgvalue::boolean
      into truefalse
    from cfg where cfglabel = 'DO_NOT_DISPLAY_WORK_ITEMS_IN_RECEIPT_CONFIRMATION_WIN';
```

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name I'm assiging the result into a table column that is unfortunately of text type, legacy and all that..